# What happened with Frank at the van dealership?

Tags: plot-explanation, oceans-eleven

I'm a big fan of *Ocean's 11*, but during the planning phase of the heist, Frank makes an unusual deal with the car salesman and I did not quite exactly understand his method of winning the deal. Was it subtle threatening or was it subtle homosexual hinting? Anyhow Frank ends up winning the deal. I just did not understand that bit.

Comment: just answer the question, no editing

Comment: Community editing in order to improve the question is part of how these sites work and part of the reason why they gather such high-quality content over time. For more information, see the [corresponding section in the help center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/editing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Anyhow Frank ends up winning the deal

He didn't exactly *win* ......but **he did make a very good deal**.

He used conversational tactical moves to throw off the salesman so that the usual sales tactics would not only be ineffective but actively turned back on the salesman.

He indicated strength with the strong (crushing) handshake and made the sales man uncomfortable by not letting go and, at the same time, subtly mentioning soft skin as, perhaps, an *effeminate* trait....something that usually goes unsaid.

All this encourages the salesman to *get away* from Frank and make a less than advantageous deal.